# How do I handle comments for review questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Basically two questions in one:

1. When I see a review canidate for deletion, e.g. it is often a 'link answer', but already has a comment telling the answerer why it is wrong. I feel it more constructive to let this go and let the answerer see the comment, vs. voting to delete the answer. Do I skip, or say it Looks OK?
2. When I see a post I feel needs improving, often I think a simple comment will suffice, vs. editing the post. Do I make a comment and Skip, or make a comment and say Looks OK?

Comment: regarding 1: Answers can and will be undeleted as soon as they are improved. Hit **Recommend Deletion**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***To your first question:***

Do not click *Looks OK*. By clicking *Looks OK* you are saying the answer is fine and doesn't need any improvements. Link only answers are to be deleted in almost all circumstances. By clicking *Looks OK* you are doing a disservice to the people who correctly flagged those posts as *Not An Answer* and leaving bad answers visible on the site. So what you should do in these cases is click *Recommend Deletion* and choose the appropriate reason. If someone already left the reason you choose, that's OK, it will just give that comment an upvote. The answerer can either improve their answer right when they see the first comment or they can check their deleted answers and see why it was deleted, improve it, then undelete it.